# add number filed to date filed in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic

I am trying to add seconds to an existing date to find the end time. I have start time in one field and total duration in one field , i find in internet that we can add number to date but we should to dived on 86400

```
(chargestarttime + (NVL (callduration, 0) / 86400))
// where chargestarttime is date , callduration is number 
// sample (chargestarttime  is 2020-05-30 02:21:58 and callduration is 65 the output is 2020-05-30 02:23:03)
```

my question is why we need to div on **86400** ? if I convert the date to UNIX_TIMESTAMP and then add just the 65 it will give the same result without div on 86400 (24 hours) or there are a reason that we div on 86400 (24 hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why we need to div on 86400?

In date arithmetics, Oracle uses `1` to represent 1 day. If you start from a number of seconds, you need to convert that to days, so

```
 chargestarttime + NVL(callduration, 0) / 60 / 60 / 24
               -- seconds per minutes-----^
                      -- minutes per hour -----^
                              -- hours per day -----^
```

`86400` is just the number of seconds there is in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is adding seconds as a fraction of a whole day (i.e. 1 day = 24 hours = 1440 minutes = 86400 seconds).

Alternatively, you could add seconds directly to the date using an `INTERVAL` data type:

```sql
chargestarttime + NVL(callduration, 0) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

or

```sql
chargestarttime + NUMTODSINTERVAL( NVL(callduration, 0), 'SECOND' )
```